# What does a "pass" mean in Assembly compiling

Tags: assembly

Just as I asked in my question,
what is a pass in the Assembly code compiling process , thanks to explain

Comment: This question has been asked and answered at stack overflow, so it may be closed as a duplicate.  The answers given here are good, I want to add that from other discussions on other tickets, a multi pass assembler usually has to do with a pass through the source code it self.  A single pass will go through data pulled from the source multiple times, but that supposedly doesnt count as a two or three pass assembler/compiler.

Answer (score 3):

In order to generate an object file, the assembler needs to do two things translate each instruction mnemonic into instruction bytes, e.g. `add eax, ds:[eax]` to `0x0000`.

Some of these are easy to do, since all the information is contained in the instruction.  However, some instructions have references to elements outside the instruction, such as:

- jumps, which have a jump target
- pointers to memory locations in data accesses

If the jump target or memory location have already been seen, there's no problem.  However, assembly doesn't limit you to accessing locations that have been seen (such as C, which only allows you to use identifiers that were defined at an earlier point in the file), so there may be cases where an identifier isn't known yet.  For instance:

```
  cmp eax, 0
  jz skip_this
  add eax, edx

skip_this:
  mov ecx, eax
```

In this example, `skip_this` isn't known when the `jz` is encountered, so the assembler doesn't know what address to put there.

In order to build the object file, the assembler processes the assembly file one line at a time.  It translates what it can, and keeps track of what it still doesn't know yet.  By the end of this stage, all of the identifiers have been encountered.

When the assembler finishes this stage, it processes the assembly file again and fills in the blanks.

Now, to answer your question, each of this stages of processing the entire source file from beginning to end is called a **pass**.

Answer (score 0):

"Pass" means exactly that -- a "pass" through the source.  Back in the days of punch cards you'd have to feed the deck through for as many passes as the assembler/compiler required.

Many old assemblers were "two pass", meaning the "deck" was fed through once to calculate code offsets, and a second time to generate the code (which was, of course, punched on cards).

With more modern setups, of course, you wouldn't notice if an assembler were 10 passes (except for the poor performance) since it's all off of disk with no user interaction between passes.

There are also "phases", and a compiler (more than an assembler) might be "two-phase" or "three-phase" or more, depending on how many transformations the code makes going through from source to final object output.